# javascript toggle table row background color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have some javascript code which on a table row click exapnds all subsequent table rows until it finds the same table row class again.

If you hover over a row it changes to gray which is what i expected.

The only stuff that doesn't work is when you click on the table row, i want the table row background color to be same as the hover (gray). the color should disappear when you click back and collapse the row.

I tried to add a toggle class as seen below.

```
$('.my-class').click(function(){

    $(this).nextUntil('tr.my-class').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass("tr.my-class.negative.clicked");
});
```

But I am not sure if that is the right approach.
Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DhdRG/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an heads up. 
This worked too and this might be a better solution:

```
$('.my-class').click(function(){

    $(this).nextUntil('tr.my-class').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DhdRG/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the class with the same event

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/DhdRG/4/

`$('.composite-test').toggleClass("grey");`

Comment: maybe I was not clear with my question. I just want the same tr to have background color as grey on which I have the hover

Answer (score 0):

You could try `$(this).removeClass('tr.my-class').addClass('tr.my-class.negative.clicked');` instead of `$(this).toggleClass('tr.my-class.negative.clicked')` But replace `$(this)` with the clicked tr's id.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle another CSS class to have the table row background color to be same as the hover (gray).
http://jsfiddle.net/DhdRG/5/

```
$('.my-class').click(function(){

    $(this).nextUntil('tr.my-class').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass("tr.my-class.negative.clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass("rowBg"); // added this line
});
```

---

CSS

```
.rowBg { background:gray;}
```